# feedback on difference between javascript and php regular expressions

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have been doing some testing with the differences between JavaScript and PHP regular expressions and "I believe" that the following 2 expressions are pretty much exactly the same thing, but I would like to ask the gurus here to confim this or not before I add these to my production code.

**PHP Version**

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]/', '_', $str);
```

**JavaScript Version**

```
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d\.\-\_]/g, "_");
```

Thx,
Dave Keltz

Comment: I was speaking of functionality like miniteck pointed out not so much how they were formatted. Thx for the reply tho.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was wrong about PHP syntax anyway, so I'll delete my previous comment so it doesn't lead people astray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're identical in functionality. Of course, you can shorten both to this:

```
/[^\w\.-]/
```

[PHP Demo](http://codepad.org/6IQWHF4y)
[JavaScript Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruW3R/)

Comment: Thx, I was pretty sure they were, but I just needed someone else with more knowledge then myself to confirm it. As for shortining things goes I kinda like it the way it is now because it's easier for me to understand if I ever have to not edit it at a later point in time.